# jquery append() display abnormally

Tags: jquery

i am trying to append table row but it is not displaying properly instead of adding the row downwardly it is adding it to the side,
here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addbtn').on('click', function(){
           var len = $('input:checked').parent().siblings('td').length;
            var tablechild;
            $('input:checked').each(function(){
                 $this = $(this);
                 tablechild = $('.orderpanel').append("<tr>");
                   for(i=0; i<len; i++){
                      tablechild += $('.orderpanel').append("<td>");

                      tablechild += $('.orderpanel').append($this.parent().siblings('td').eq(i).text());
                      tablechild += $('.orderpanel').append("</td>");
                    }   
                   tablechild += $('.orderpanel').append("</tr>");
              });
     });
  });
```

and here is my html table

```
<TABLE class="orderpanel" style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse; border: solid 1px #000000"><TBODY>


</TBODY></TABLE>
```

i am just at a cross road need help, thanks in advance

Comment: You're appending after the tbody. Surely you want to append to the tbody? `$('.orderpanel tbody').append()`

Comment: That's not how DOM works, you can't insert the opening and closing tags separately.

Comment: append is not the same as string concatenation!!!

Comment: In fact, as undefined says, your DOM manipulation is just wrong in general :o

Comment: can you share your html

Comment: @MasNotsram, thanks for your quick response, i needed to append it to the tbody, i have also taken note of the DOM mistake i made, thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is doing what you think it's doing:

```
tablechild = $('.orderpanel').append("<tr>");
tablechild += $('.orderpanel').append("<td>");
```

This would likely result in invalid markup:

```
<table>
    <tbody class="orderpanel">
        <tr></tr>
        <td></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead, build the entire node as one string and append the whole thing when it's done.  Something like this:

```
var newRow = "<tr>";
for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
    newRow += "<td>";
    newRow += $this.parent().siblings('td').eq(i).text();
    newRow += "</td>";
}   
newRow += "</tr>";
$('.orderpanel').append(newRow);
```